# populating array of arrays with distinct values

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, foreach

I have an array of array with elements for example:

```
var one = [1span,2span,3span,4span,5span,6span,7span];
var two = [1span,2span,3span,4span,5span,6span,7span];
var three = [1span,2span,3span,4span,5span,6span,7span];
var ...till seven.
var total = [one,two,three ..till 7]
```

so basically we have 7 arrays and `total variable` will display 7 elements for each one of all 7 arrays.

now I have a function that should populate my variables with distinct numbers from 1 to 7 on each section.

```
   var bar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    for(var j=0; j<total.length; j++) {
      Array.from(total[j]).forEach(function(e, i, a) {
       e.textContent = bar[Math.round(Math.random()*(bar.length-1))];
      console.log(e,i,k);
});
    }
```

all good my function does that but unfortunately is populating span elements with values from `bar variable` for each variable from `total var` 7 times for each and should populate just once for each variable.

So my problem is:

1. I want to populate each variable from `total var` with values from `bar array` just once.
2. The values should be randomly and unique for each variable.

Comment: Where have you defined `arr` variable?

Comment: @Mr_Green ah arr should be bar variable, I have edited, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an copy of the given array and generate random items without repeat.

```js
function generate(count, values) {
    return Array.apply(null, { length: count }).map(function () {
        var r = [],
            array = values.slice();
        while (array.length) {
            r.push(array.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length), 1)[0]);
        }
        return r;
    });
}

console.log(generate(7, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]));
```

Randomize a single array

```js
function generate(values) {
    var r = [],
        array = values.slice();
    while (array.length) {
        r.push(array.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length), 1)[0]);
    }
    return r;
}

console.log(generate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]));
```

Comment: Hi Nina, thank;s for your effort but I'm a little bit confused, how do I apply generate() function for each of my variables from total var  :|

Comment: it would be easier, if you add a possible result to your question.

Comment: basically I should insert the given array from your example into my table. The problem is that iterating through the table cells and adding a value on each cell but unfortunately is adding all interval in a cell :|  .  see the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/truvh94a/3/

Comment: you could just generate one array `e.textContent = generate(1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);` instead of 7. but then you need a smaller function, just one for one and not for 7. or use the second proposal.

Comment: I think you have misunderstand, the idea is I have the  board 7x7 thanks to your first script that I have modified a little bit adding a "for loop" bit to receive an array for each line, my problem is how to iterate the board result and add them into my grid. So basically the result of your script should be added into my html by adding one number in one cell and one line array on one grid row.

Comment: this would require to build the structure inside the object, where the random numbers are.

Answer (score 1):

If we would like to extend the question for a general case of an N dimensional array filled with random integers then a reusable approach could be as follows;

We will use two generic functions that i like to use very much; `Array.prototype.clone()` and `Array.prototype.shuffle()`. Our `arrayND` function takes indefinite number of arguments. The last argument will designate the minimum (base) of the random integer to be filled. Previous arguments will give the length of each dimension. So in the particular case as we will need a 2D 7x7 matrice to be filled with random but unique numbers in each starting from 1, we shall invoke our function as `arrayND(7,7,1)`

```js
Array.prototype.shuffle = function(){
  var i = this.length,
      j;
  while (i > 1) {
    j = ~~(Math.random()*i--);
    [this[i],this[j]] = [this[j],this[i]];
  }
return this;
};

Array.prototype.clone = function(){
  return this.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? e.clone() : e);
};

function arrayND(...n){
  return n.reduceRight((p,c) => c = Array(...Array(c)).map((e,i) => Array.isArray(p) ? p.clone().shuffle() : i+p));
}

var arr = arrayND(7,7,1);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

since you want these Arrays to be processed together you should put them together into a data-structure:

```
var spans = [ one, two, tree, ..., seven ]
```

now you want a random order without repetition, put the possible indices into an Array and shuffle that:

```
var indices = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

and some shuffler:

```
function shuffle(arr){
    for(var i=arr.length, j, tmp; i-- > 1; ){
        tmp = arr[j = 0|(Math.random()*i)];
        arr[j] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = tmp;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

now if you want the Nodes for total:

```
var total = shuffle(indices).map((index, n) => spans[n][index]);
```

at least as far as I understand your question/code/intentions.